# Centering text within an centered element, Css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a card on the page and center the text within that card. Here is the CSS I've attempted below. And It seems to do nothing. I am trying to use JS for the first time with CSS. Confusion about where I'm messing up, so not entirely sure what part to isolate to share.

sample here: https://rrrhhhhhhhhh.github.io/sentences/

Thank you

CSS

```
    .testclass {
            font: 10px courier, courier new;
            background: #ffffff;
            z-index: 10;
            layer-background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    #test {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left:10px;
            padding: 0px;
    }

    #rel {
          position: relative;
          align: center;
    }
```

html and js

```
}
function writit(text,id)
{
        if (document.getElementById)
        {
                x = document.getElementById(id);
                x.innerHTML = '';
                x.innerHTML = text;
        }
        else if (document.all)
        {
                x = document.all[id];
                x.innerHTML = text;
        }
        else if (document.layers)
        {
                x = document.layers[id];
        l = (480-(getNumLines(text)*8))/2;
        w = (764-(getWidestLine(text)*8))/2;
                text2 = '<td id=rel align="center" CLASS="testclass" style="font:12px courier,courier new;padding-left:' + w.toString() + 'px' + ';padding-top:' + l.toString() + 'px' + '">' + text + '</td>';
                x.document.open();
                x.document.write(text2);
                x.document.close();
        }
}
function getNumLines(mystr)
{
  var a = mystr.split("<br>")
  return(a.length);
}
function getWidestLine(mystr)
{
  if (mystr.indexOf("&nbsp;") != -1)
  {
    re = /&nbsp;*/g;
    mystr = mystr.replace(re,"Z");
    //alert(mystr);
  }
  if (mystr.indexOf("<u>") != -1)
  {
    re = /<u>*/g;
        mystr = mystr.replace(re, "");
        re = /<\/u>*/g;
    mystr = mystr.replace(re, "");
  }

  if (mystr.indexOf("<br>") != -1)
  {
    var ss, t;
    var lngest;
    ss = mystr.split("<br>");
    lngest = ss[0].length;
    for (t=0; t < ss.length; t++)
    {
      if (ss[t].length > lngest)
      {
        lngest = ss[t].length;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    lngest = mystr.length;
  }
  return(lngest);
}
// -->

</script>
<body bgcolor="gainsboro" onload="startup();">


<table bgcolor="white" border height="480px" width="764px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table nowrap>
<tr>
<td><img width="700px" height="1px" src="./resources/images/w.gif"></td>
<td>
<div class="testclass" id="test"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<center>
<form>
<p>

<input type="button" onclick="doBack(); return false" value="Back">
<input type="button" onclick="doNext(); return false" value="Next">
</p>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't have the things your asking about. Theirs no text to center, and the bordered div (which I guess is your card?) is already centered, Unless you explain further its hard to know exactly how to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using JS for the first time and getting a bit lost. I will try and update post. Honestly not sure how to do it without including all the code. which is a no no as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just notice this without js

```css
.testclass {
        font: 10px courier,courier new;
        background: #ffffff;
        z-index: 10;
        layer-background-color: #ffffff;
}

#test {position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left:10px;
        padding: 0px;
}

#rel {position: relative;
      align: center;
}
.center-div{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Robert Grenier - Sentences</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="center-div">
<table bgcolor="white" border height="480px" width="764px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table nowrap>
<tr>
<td><img width="700px" height="1px" src="./resources/images/w.gif"></td>
<td>
<div class="testclass" id="test"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<center>
<form>
<p>

<input type="button" onclick="doBack(); return false" value="Back">
<input type="button" onclick="doNext(); return false" value="Next">
</p>
</form>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).